# Default Boot Device Missing or Boot failed

Tags: boot, acer

I wiped out Windows 10 from my Acer Aspire E15 to install Ubuntu 18.10 in single-boot. The installation worked but I keep getting at boot time a blue window with this message :

« Default Boot Device Missing or Boot failed. Insert recovery media and hit any key ».

Hitting a key would lead me to a Boot Option Menu with two entries:

1. Unknown Device : (ST500LT012-1DG142) (which is supposed to be my hard drive)
2. Yes

I searched on the net and tried some of the suggested solutions but none seems to work since I don't have problem with booting. Indeed when I select 1. then the boot works and everything is alright so I'm wondering whether there is something I have to fix and or not.

Any suggestion?

I could reinstall Ubuntu from scratch, but since I've already installed many application I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: Acer normally needs you to enable "trust" if UEFI booting. Did you install in the old BIOS/MBR configuration? Then it may give errors on UEFI boot and then go to the BIOS boot. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: assuming your installation is on UEFI, It may be possible that the windows boot files are still there in the efi partition and those files are top on boot order for your machine.

Comment: Thank you. So @anjanik012 how do you think  I can fix it?

Comment: @Serena There is an option to change boot order in UEFI settings. Or you can change boot order from ubuntu using a tool efibootmgr

Answer (score 0):

I've been running Lubuntu for some time, and I just got this issue out of nowhere. It couldn't find my hard disk. I opened up my laptop, and I noticed the SSD was not fully seated. I guess it gradually got loose. I just pushed it in, and now everything works.

This sounds a like a lame answer, but just throwing it out there.